# In a right triangle, the midpoint of the hypotenuse is equidistant from all three vertices

Tags: geometry

In the AMC 10 B 2017 contest, question 21 states that "In $\triangle ABC$, $AB=6$, $AC=8$, $BC=10$, and $D$ is the midpoint of $\overline{BC}$. What is the sum of the radii of the circles inscribed in $\triangle ADB$ and $\triangle ADC$?" When I saw the solution, it explained how $AD=BD=CD=5$. Though it is obvious that $AD=BD=5$, I wasn't sure why $CD$ was $5$.

Comment: If you would like me to explain my problem more, please ask.

Comment: I think you mean that the "obvious" fact is $BD=CD=5$, since $D$ is the midpoint of $BC$. In any case, to see that all three lengths are equal, simply observe that a right triangle is half of a rectangle, and that $D$ would be the center of that rectangle.

Comment: Do you need anymore help?  Like solving the problem?

Comment: @Xcoderx Thank you. I fully understand the question now.

Answer (score 1):

Since ABC is right angle ∆, BC is the diameter of it's circumcircle, and D being it's midpoint is the centre of the circle, so AD=BD=CD